# Validar edad JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Al introducir la edad en un formulario usando JSF tengo que verificar que la edad se encuentra en un rango determinado y si no mostrar un mensaje de fecha no válida.
Había pensado en usar código en Java que tenía implementado de otros años en una clase que implementa validator. El problema es que no sé cómo manejar el parámetro que se pasa en el método de cálculo.
Dejo el código:

**Formulario**

```
<body>

    <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/Template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
          <h:form>

              <f:event listener="#{registerView.validarPassword}" type="postValidate" />
              <p:panel header="Crear una nueva cuenta">
                  <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="3">
                      <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Nombre:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:inputText id="name" value="#{registerView.name}" required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Introduzca su nombre." maxlength="30"/>
                      <p:message for="name"/>


                      <h:outputLabel for="apellidos" value="Apellidos:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:inputText id="apellidos" value="#{registerView.apellidos}" required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Introduzca sus apellidos." maxlength="30"/>
                      <p:message for="apellidos"/>

                      <h:outputLabel for="email" value="E-Mail:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:inputText id="email" value="#{registerView.email}" required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Introduzca su email.">
                         <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
                      </p:inputText>

                      <p:message for="email"/>

                      <h:outputLabel for="fechanac" value="Fecha de nacimiento:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:inputText type="Date" id="fechanac" value="#{registerView.fechanac}" required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Introduzca su fecha de nacimiento.">

                      </p:inputText>

                      <p:message for="fechanac"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="tarjeta" value="tarjeta de crédito:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:inputText id="tarjeta" value="#{registerView.tarjeta}" required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Introduzca su tarjeta de crédito." onkeypress="if (event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;">
                        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"/>

                      </p:inputText>

                      <p:message for="tarjeta"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="movil" value="Móvil(opcional):" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:inputText id="movil" value="#{registerView.movil}" required="false"/>




                      <p:message for="movil"/>



                      <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Contraseña:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:password id="password" value="#{registerView.password}" feedback="true"
                                  required="true" requiredMessage="Introduzca su contraseña."
                                  validatorMessage="La contraseña debe contener al menos un número,
                                 así como caracteres tanto en mayúscula como en minúscula, además de 
                                 contar con una longitud comprendida entre 6 y 20 caracteres alfanuméricos">
                          <f:validateRegex pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})" />
                      </p:password>
                      <p:message for="password"/>
                      <h:outputLabel for="confirmpassword" value="Confirmar contraseña:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
                      <p:password id="confirmpassword" feedback="true"
                                  value="#{registerView.confirmPassword}" required="true"
                                  requiredMessage="Por favor, confirma tu contraseña."/>
                      <p:message for="confirmpassword"/>
                  </h:panelGrid>

                  <p:commandButton value="Registrarse" ajax="false" action="#{registerView.register}"/> 

              </p:panel>
          </h:form>

        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

**Código Java de validador**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

import javax.faces.validator.Validator;

@FacesValidator("agevalidator")
public class AgeValidator implements Validator {
public int GetAge(String fecha_nac) {     //fecha_nac debe tener el formato dd/MM/yyyy

Date fechaActual = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String hoy = formato.format(fechaActual);
String[] date1 = fecha_nac.split("/");
String[] date2 = hoy.split("/");
int anios = Integer.parseInt(date2[2]) - Integer.parseInt(date1[2]);
int mes = Integer.parseInt(date2[1]) - Integer.parseInt(date1[1]);
if (mes < 0) {
  anios = anios - 1;
} else if (mes == 0) {
  int dia = Integer.parseInt(date2[0]) - Integer.parseInt(date1[0]);
  if (dia > 0) {
    anios = anios - 1;
  }
}
return anios;
}
 @Override
 public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (value == null) {
     return;
    }
}
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al implementar **Validator**, el valor ingresado por el usuario llega en el argumento **value** de la firma del método.
Para el caso que subiste el valor ingresado lo obtendrías así:

```
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        //Fecha ingresada por el usuario
        String fechaDeNacimiento = String.class.cast(value); 
    }
```

Ahora, hay cierto contrato que respetar cuando usamos un Validator de JSF y es que, en caso de que la validación no pase, se debe lanzar una excepción del tipo **ValidatorException**.

Por otro lado, no entiendo bien tu regla de negocio para validar la fecha de nacimiento. Es algo complejo el tratamiento que estas realizando. Creo que te sería mas fácil usar un Converter para definir como transformar de texto plano a un objeto de tipo fecha cuando se hace el POST. De esa manera, podrías usar una validación más orientada a objetos usando Joda Time o (que es lo mismo) la api de fechas de Java 8. Te muestro este ejemplo a ver si te aclara un poco lo que te digo:

Quiero validar que el usuario no sea menor de edad (supongamos que la mayoría de edad es a los 18 años)

```
    <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <p:outputLabel value="Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento (dd/MM/yyyy)" for="fechaNacimiento"/>
            <p:inputText id="fechaNacimiento"
                value="#{controladorFechaNacimiento.fechaNacimiento}"
                converter="jodaLocalDateConverter"
                validator="validadorFechaNacimiento"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Si te fijas, al componente  le paso dos atributos: converter y validator.

JodaLocalDateConverter: Se encarga de representar el objeto como texto a la hora de dibujar el html, y de convertir el texto a objeto cuando se realiza el post:

```
    @FacesConverter("jodaLocalDateConverter")
    public class JodaLocalDateConverter implements Converter { 

        private DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");    
        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
            String value) {

            return formatter.parseDateTime(value).toLocalDate();
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent 
        component, Object value) {

            return formatter.print((LocalDate) value);
       }
    }
```

Y por último el validador de fecha de nacimiento:

```
    @FacesValidator("validadorFechaNacimiento")
    public class ValidadorFechaNacimiento implements Validator {

        private static final int EDAD_MINIMA_PERMITIDA = 18;

        @Override
        public void validate(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent 
        componente, Object valor) throws ValidatorException {

            //El objeto valor es de tipo LocalDate porque el converter JodaLocalDateConverter
            //invoco al metodo getAsObject
            LocalDate fechaNacimiento = new LocalDate(valor);        
            Years anios = Years.yearsBetween(fechaNacimiento, 
            LocalDate.now());

            if (anios.getYears() < EDAD_MINIMA_PERMITIDA) {

                FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Edad no 
                             permitida", "Debes tener más de " + EDAD_MINIMA_PERMITIDA + " para ingresar");
                facesMessage.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage);
            }        
        }
    }
```

Me extendí un poco pero espero te sea útil

Comment: OK:Muchas gracias, me ha sido de utilidad

Comment: Me alegro Iskandarina que te haya servido. Si puedes, marcala como útil, así a otras personas que tengan el mismo problema o misma duda que tu les puede ser útil.